# how to get field value of a field in this class

Tags: java, reflection, field

I want to iterate over class fields in the following way

i have class

```
public class Parent{

String name;
String lastName;

}

public class Child extends Parent{

int childNumber;
}
```

in the parent class i want to have a "get" method

that the child will inherit

this method will return the value of a field by its name

how do i retreive the field's value ?

i want the method to be like this:

```
public Object get(String key){
            Field field;
        Object result = null;
        try {
            field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(key);
            if(field!=null) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }
            result = field.get(this); // this is where my problem, i don't know how to retrieve the field's value
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.database.User.userID to java.lang.String
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.database.DatabaseObject.get(DatabaseObject.java:106)
    at com.database.DatabaseObject.set(DatabaseObject.java:128)
    at com.database.DatabaseObject.getInsertPreparedStatement(DatabaseObject.java:64)
    at com.database.Database.insert(Database.java:95)
    at com.lenabru.webservice.ElectronicArenaWebService.register(ElectronicArenaWebService.java:21)
    at com.database.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

Comment: What doesn't work about the code snippet you gave?

Comment: i put the stack trace in the post, java thinks i am trying to set the field, and not get it

Comment: Could you maybe show how you are using the code? (What `this` is referring to and the name of the field you are trying to access?)

Answer (score 1):

To get this stack trace you would have to have passed a string value to `field.get`, not `this`. Do a full rebuild and test again.

Here are the relevant methods from the `UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl` class, as you can see you can only get the given, confusing, error message if you try to pass in a String instead of an object assignable from the class where the field is declared:

```
protected void ensureObj(Object o) {
    // NOTE: will throw NullPointerException, as specified, if o is null
    if (!field.getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) {
        throwSetIllegalArgumentException(o);
    }
}

protected void throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Object o) {
    throwSetIllegalArgumentException(o != null ? o.getClass().getName() : "", "");
}

protected void throwSetIllegalArgumentException(String attemptedType,
                                                String attemptedValue) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(getSetMessage(attemptedType,attemptedValue));
}

protected String getSetMessage(String attemptedType, String attemptedValue) {
    String err = "Can not set";
    if (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
        err += " static";
    if (isFinal)
        err += " final";
    err += " " + field.getType().getName() + " field " + getQualifiedFieldName() + " to ";
    if (attemptedValue.length() > 0) {
        err += "(" + attemptedType + ")" + attemptedValue;
    } else {
        if (attemptedType.length() > 0)
            err += attemptedType;
        else
            err += "null value";
    }
    return err;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do one of two things:

1. If your real code has as few fields as the example you show here, add a `getXxx()` method for each field. For example, `Parent` should have `getName()` (should this be `getFirstName()`?) and `getLastName()` methods and `Child` should have `getChildNumber()`.
2. If your code is more complex than this, use a `Map` and implement your `get()` and `set()` methods by delegating to the `Map`.

Reflection is intended for programmers building complex tools that need to manipulate objects at a very low level. There are often better solutions for the rest of us.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way to use `BeanUtils` from `commons-beanutils` if you want get access to bean fields:

```
System.out.println(BeanUtils.getProperty(child, "name")); // get value from property

BeanUtils.setProperty(c, "lastName", "Ivan Ivanov"); // set value to property
```